# Generate png using Graphviz 2.38.0 on Anaconda Python 2.7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphviz, pygraphviz

When I do this :

> G.draw('file.png')

I have the following error :

> Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np
>   dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg
>   svgz tk vml vmlz xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4

I tried to run

```
dot -c
```

This does not seem to change anything.

To install (or reinstall) Graphviz
I did use :

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/mutirri graphviz`

Output of dot -v

```
render      :  dot fig map pic pov ps svg tk vml xdot
layout      :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
textlayout  :
device      :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4
loadimage   :  (lib) eps gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
```

Example that doesn't work :

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G=pgv.AGraph(strict=False,directed=False)
G.add_edge('A','B')
G.layout(prog='neato')
G.draw('graph.png')
```

If I replace png by svg, the example works.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how you installed `graphviz`. Have you tried reinstalling it? Also, please include the output of `dot -v` in your question.

Comment: I did edit my question and add what you asked for

Comment: Hmh, seems fine - can you create a minimal reproducible code example with a trivial example graph so we can try to reproduce this error?

Comment: I installed `pygraphviz` with pip and `graphviz` from `mutirri`'s binstar channel as you did on my mac. Your code works fine for me and I do get the graph as a `png` file.

Comment: It's weird, I am on ubuntu and it doesn't work.

Comment: pip inside anaconda with Python2.7, yes ?

Comment: I may have problems with PATH, I changed it to look into the right bin and sbin folders. Is there another folder I would have to add to the PATH ?

Comment: This is because my Anaconda has both Python 3 and Python 2.7, I have the good kernel but with the PATH of Python 3. I changed at the beginning of my script the PATH so that it'll look into the good folders. Do you think it might be the reason ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78399/discussion-between-cel-and-davidk).